# pythonでの集合処理で全てのkeyが結果として出てしまう

Tags: python

現在入門python3を使用し勉強しております。
value中にベルモットかオレンジジュースが入っているkeyを取り出したいのですが、
下記のコードではすべてのkeyの名前が結果として出てしまいます。理由を教えてくださると幸いです。

```
drinks = {
 "martini": {"vodka", "vermouth"},
 "black russian": {"vodka", "kahlua"},
 "white russian": {"cream", "kahlua", "vodka"},
 "manhattan": {"rye", "vermouth", "bitters"},
 "screwdriver": {"orange juice", "vodka"}
 }
for key, value in drinks.items():
    if "vermouth" or "orange juice" in value:
        print(key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのように書くと、`if ("vermouth") or ("orange juice" in value):`と書いたのと同じとなり、文字列単独では必ず`True`なので全て成立し、`print`することになります。

Answer (score 1):

`in`が`or`よりも優先順位が高いため、ifが常に真になってしまうからです。

次のように書けば、お望みの結果が得られると思います。

```
if ("vermouth" in value) or ("orange juice" in value):
```

以下のように、適当な文字列を書いても真になりました。※知らなかった

```
if "XXX":
```